# Can commendations offset reports in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

In one of my **Dota** games, the entire team was threatening to **report** a player who was intentionally feeding courier and killing himself.

That player was claiming since he has lots of commendations, they offset reports.

Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not true. Reports work the same way no matter the amount of commendations a player may have.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, several reports from the same party in the same game is worth less than from several different parties in several different games. Reports are made to punish "bad behavior over time", as in players who consistently behaves bad.

Comment: How do you know this? Valve has been secretive. I remember when it was possible to see your behaviour score as a number via the `dota_game_account_client_debug` command, mine went up by a small amount when I got commended, and down by a large amount when I had to abandon. Given that the behaviour score is [in some way used for matchmaking](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Matchmaking#Behavior_Score_and_Account_Flags), the claim that "commendations offset reports" sounds possibly true at least to some small degree.

Comment: Behaviour score is affected by reports, but the opposite is not true. I've never seen proof of commendations offsetting reports since reports were last changed. With such a huge playerbase, we would've heard something about if it were true.

Answer (score -1):

Also, independent of the amount of reports, if they investigate the chat logs, just he saying that about the commendations and admitting hes griefing, will get him properly punished

Comment: Outside of extraordinary circumstances, reports are not individually investigated.